# Export psql results to csv with proper boolean values

Tags: java, postgresql, csv

I am currently obtaining a csv string from psql using copyManager in a java service.

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM table";
copyManager.copyOut("COPY (" + selectQuery + ") TO STDOUT WITH CSV HEADER", csaString);
```

But in the resulting string, all boolean values are as `'t'/'f'`. How do I get the boolean values as `'true'` or `'false'`. Is there some configuration I can provide to do this?

This table has a lot of columns, so if I used a case to change it, I will also have to specify all the other columns which I want to avoid.

Comment: you don't need `case` - just cast boolean column as text. but you still need to list columns then

Comment: is there a way I can cast all columns as text?

Comment: no, nothing comes to my mind

Answer (score 5):

there's no configuration for that I'm afraid. The best you could do is casting boolean columns as text. You will have to list columns of course...

example:

```
db=# select *,is_dst::text from pg_timezone_names limit 1;
      name      | abbrev | utc_offset | is_dst | is_dst
----------------+--------+------------+--------+--------
 Africa/Abidjan | GMT    | 00:00:00   | f      | false
(1 row)
```

[Here are Toms thoughts on it](http://grokbase.com/p/postgresql/pgsql-general/02a5fn5gq5/boolean-output-format)